# iOS how to read bluetoothd service logs in the console?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, console

I’m debugging a Bluetooth app on an iPhone. When I connect it via cable to a Mac, I see that Apple logs output from “bluetoothd” service in between my app’s output. The logs contain central/ peripheral events, incoming requests, rssi info, etc.

**Where can I find documentation to understand what is happening with bluetoothd ata hardware level?**

I’m looking for information like “this hen I see packet X, the connection state is Y”, or “this message means the device has reconnected to a service Z”

Answer (score 0):

Apple does a good job in my opinion with bluetooth and debugging.

- https://developer.apple.com/bluetooth/

Specifically, you can use the diagnostic profile to get excellent details and a step by step guide to setting things up to make it easier to understand what the codes mean.

- https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/?name=bluetooth

The bluetooth explorer is also far superior to trying to decode raw hex values in my experience. I try to avoid getting into the raw bytes / physical interface unless there’s no other option.